# Calculating of expectation

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I've found this formula in a blog, it is in the answer to one question. But I don't know how to prove this:

> Let $x_n$ be a sum of $n$ i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables with parameter $1/2$. Let $q\geq 2$.
>   Show that 
>   $$
> E((2x_n-n)^q)=\sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k}2^{-n}(2k-n)^q
> $$

Thank you for your help.

Comment: That does not make sense. I guess you mean $x_n$ is the sum of $n$ Bernoulli variables?

Comment: You are right. It was typo. Thank you

Comment: Michael: Why not asking directly this question [there](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/139441/6179)? To call MSE *a blog* is a bit deceptive, wouldn't you say?

Comment: @dif: I am very dorry. I've had an experience when I' ve asked question in the comment and someone told me that I have to ask questions separately... Si, this time I' ve asked separate question. Sorry for my mistake. It would not happened again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be a random variable that, for simplicity, can only take on the values $x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n$. Suppose moreover that $P(X=x_k)=p_k$. Let $f$ be any real-valued function defined at least on the $x_k$. Then it is a standard fact that
$$E(f(X))=\sum_{k=0}^n f(x_k)p_k.$$
The result quoted is a special case of this, with $x_k=k$, and $X$ having binomial distribution with $p=1/2$, and $f(x)=(2x-n)^q$.