# calculation of the sum using idea of one answer

Tags: combinatorics, sequences-and-series, statistics, binomial-coefficients

I am wondering if the sum (the $q$-th moment) in my question [Calculation of the moments using Hypergeometric distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/154231/30554) can be calculated using idea in [Evaluating 'combinatorial' sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/139189/30554) ?

Thank you.